# Powershell manipulate output of & cmd .exe script

Tags: powershell

Im using HTTP Azure functions with powershell 7.0 and i need to run a cmd .exe script and then return in the http response body, when the script runs it just prints in the console the OUTPUT: but i cant find how to manipulate that output and assign that into the response body...

Here is my code:

```
    # Input bindings are passed in via param block.
    param($Request, $TriggerMetadata)
    
    # Write to the Azure Functions log stream.
    Write-Host "PowerShell HTTP trigger function processed a request."
    
    # Interact with query parameters or the body of the request.
    $name = $Request.Query.Name
    if (-not $name) {
        $name = $Request.Body.Name
    }
    
#This is the powershell command that runs the script
    & "C:\home\site\wwwroot\myScript.exe" <argument_A argument_B argument_C>
#This is what prints in the console:
#2021-07-02T19:39:34.720 [Information] OUTPUT: [My output]
    

#I need the output set in the $body variable...
    $body = "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
    
    if ($name) {
        $body = "Hello, $name. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully."
    }
    
    # Associate values to output bindings by calling 'Push-OutputBinding'.
    Push-OutputBinding -Name Response -Value ([HttpResponseContext]@{
        StatusCode = [HttpStatusCode]::OK
        Body = $body
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do:

```
$body = & "C:\home\site\wwwroot\myScript.exe" <argument_A argument_B argument_C>
```

That will assign to $body the value of the cmd output